# Cannot call value of non-function type '[Observable<Event>.Type]'

Tags: swift, maya, rx-swift, maya-api

Xcode 15
Mac book M1

- Moya/RxSwift (15.0.0):

  - Moya/Core
  - RxSwift (~> 6.0)

> Cannot call value of non-function type '[Observable.Type]'

```
private func bindingsStrongify<Event, O, WeakOwner>(_ owner: WeakOwner, _ bindings: @escaping (WeakOwner, O) -> (Bindings<Event>))
    -> (O) -> (Bindings<Event>) where WeakOwner: AnyObject {
    return { [weak owner] state -> Bindings<Event> in
        guard let strongOwner = owner else {
            return Bindings(subscriptions: [], events: [Observable<Event>]())
        }
        return bindings(strongOwner, state)
    }
}
```

[image: error image]

@Maya
https://github.com/Moya/Moya/issues/2325

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is confusing the Swift.Observable type with the RxSwift.Observable type. Use: `return Bindings(subscriptions: [], events: [RxSwift.Observable<Event>]())` instead.